# Will using Entity framework considered to be a bad practice when developing large scale web applications

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have been using entity framework for around 1.5 years when developing asp.net mvc3 web application,, but recently during some meetings with some clients they mentioned that using a bridge between the object oriented code and the relational database as in the entity framework case have performance problems in large scale applications or if the server capabilities are not very sufficient; **since the entity framework will add extra queries when interacting with the databases to retrieve the relevant data which can be avoided if i write Sql quires directly inside my application . So should i consider writing sql queries directly inside my mvc application to directly interact with my Sql database without the need to do this through the EF.**
Best Regards

Answer (score 3):

It's a question of time and energy.  It'll be faster to develop with an entity framework then with SQL statements.

1. Get it working so it's easy to maintain
2. If there are performance issues, then Profile, ***THEN*** optimize your code

Answer (score 0):

I am been working with entity framework since last 2 years and we had not faced any big trouble till date even in big applications.

As the @Jim Barrows said

- It is very easy and fast to work with entity framework
- If it gives you the performance issue then just optimize your code.